# SublimeCodeIntel won't provide Ruby support with Sublime Text 3 on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, sublimetext3, code-completion, sublimecodeintel

I'm unable to get the plugin to work on my Sublime 3 on Windows 7 64bit. I followed the guide and installed the package using Package Control but nothing happens after I try to use it.
Tried Ctrl + Shift + Space with no success. Log file nonexistent on my system (or at least I couldn't find it).

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: which guide did you follow? Did you change any of the configuration files to point to your Ruby installation?

Comment: @MattDMo Well, I followed the instructions on their portal - [link](http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel). I then tried to edit _.codeintel\config_ file and add Ruby location but this didn't make any difference. My Ruby installation is in my PATH too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is something to do with Python3.3 in Sublime Text 3...

After numerous tries to fix this I installed Sublime Text 2 and now able to use this plugin without any issues!

**Edit#1:**
Was able to solve it for **Sublime Text 3** by following [this guide](https://johnblackbourn.com/sublimecodeintel-st3#comment-13258):

1. In the Sublime Text menu, go to Preferences -> Browse Packages. From this directory run:

   `git clone -b development git@github.com:SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel.git`
2. Clear your codeintel cache if you had older version of SublimeCodeIntel installed on your machine, i.e. `C:\Users\user\.codeintel`
3. Restart Sublime Text